How to install wordlist.txt for gobuster in ubuntu
I found this code sudo apt install wordlist and gave me a various types of wordlist like wamerican etc and these files are not the wordlist .txt file when I used the command gobuster -u (url) -w wordlist.txt dir
When I execute this command it says wordlist.txt file does not exist

Please edit and improve your previous question instead of posting a new almost identical one
